# Vue-multiselect - How to insert html code in placeholder?

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

Im trying insert span in placeholder, for color change. But placeholder returns only string, ow to fix that?

```
computed: {
      customPlaceholder () {
        let numLength = this.options.length;
        return this.placeholder + "<span>"+numLength+"</span>"
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you show all code with template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to add a custom placeholder inside an `input` field.

to do this you need some mix of `css` and `html`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    input: '',
    input2: 'some text'
  },
  computed: {
    placeholderText: function () {
      return `${this.input2} <span>*</span>`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: _.debounce(function (e) {
      this.input = e.target.value
    }, 300)
  }
})
```

```css
#editor div {
  display: inline-block;
}



.input-placeholder {
  position: relative;
}
.input-placeholder input {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.input-placeholder input:valid + .placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #ccc;
}

.placeholder span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.16.0"></script>

<div id="editor">
  <div class="input-placeholder">
    <input type="text" @input="update">
    <div class="placeholder" v-if="!input" v-html="placeholderText">
      Email <span>*</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp19zr3h/1/) for my solution.

Comment: U are awesome, Thank u

Answer (score 0):

you can use css placeholder selector

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  color: green!important;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: green!important;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: green!important;
}
```

Try it, then try to remove the `!important`.

But information is missing. You want to change the color dynamically or not? or you want to have different colours into the same placeholder?

Comment: No , i need insert html, not color, and in vue that not input

Comment: You should put more code. The component code or something so we can guess what you are talking about. You mean that is not an input... What is? a div? an span? try `v-html` example `<span v-html="customPlaceholder"></span>`

Comment: <slot name="placeholder">
            {{ placeholder }}
          </slot>